# Chrome extension interaction with Java application

Tags: java, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am learning to build Chrome extension and I have an idea to build something which requires complex computation (using many java libraries) which seems hard to be implemented by JavaScript.

A general architecture I have in mind is:

Chrome Extension (GE) extracts HTML elements and feeds HTML elements to Java application as input. Java application does the complex computation, and then feedback the results to GE. GE finally renders the results into the browser.

Does anyone know is this feasible? Does this have to involve a server architecture? Could you also refer me to some further information?

Note: It is a Java application, hopefully you can give me some Java specific answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create java web application running on server (which can be accessed via URL) which you will be communicating with through ajax requests. Chrome extension (or any other js app) doesn't care what's running on server - java, php, or something else. It just sends HTTP POST/GET request to provided url and receives response back.

If you are asking if you can pack some java into your extension then the answer is no. You can pack some C++ though.

Comment: thanks serg, seems like a server architectural is inevitable.